# attach a second router to my network to expand coverage?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I currently have one Linksys wireless router attached to a cable modem.  The router is 192.168.1.1 and is a DHCP server.  The router itself gets a dynamic IP from the cable ISP... pretty standard stuff.

What I'd like to do is connect a second router (by network cable) to one of the LAN ports on the first router and position it some distance away.  The second router would also be a DHCP server.

Is this setup possible?  If so, how would I configure the 2 routers?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I can clarify some of the other answers.

1) Setup the second "router" as an access point, or repeater. In most hardware, you don't have to disable DHCP, it will be disabled when the box is in access point mode.

2) Since this box is a repeater, if the first router is providing DHCP for the wired ports (which it should be), then computers on the wireless repeater will get DHCP from the first router. If you have any doubt, plug a laptop into the wired port on the first router and verify that it gets an address on 192.168.1.x. Make sure your router has enough IP addresses setup in DHCP config to assign to all your new computers on the repeater wireless.

3) Make sure you setup the wireless channels to be separated as much as possible, while still providing good coverage and avoiding interference with neighbor's wireless.

4) Configure a static 192.168.1.x address on the second "router" so you can always access its web interface on a known address and can put a link shortcut in your browser. You might need to configure the DHCP on the first router to accomplish this, but some DHCP servers will honor any static IP that they encounter.

5) If you haven't already bought the second router, try re-positioning the first router to get broader coverage. Maybe you don't need to buy the second router. Remember that altitude is key, as well as avoiding metal walls and aquariums. Also try switching channels for better coverage and less interference. (Sorry if this is too elementary.)

Answer (score 1):

Last year I went to a hotel that wanted to do something similar and on the advise of a previous engineer, they purchased about 20 Linksys routers.

It isn't what I would have bought if planning from scratch - but it worked very well... If you buy a new Linksys, they have a feature that allows you to extend the wireless from an existing router without any problems - you just set up the same SSID name and security key, and set up this special mode and the second will simply extend the wireless from the first one - I think it was even set on the same channel (I do not remember changing it) which is not something I have seen before.

So, you won't even need another DHCP server, it should simply allow you to connect to whichever point has the strongest signal... If you want to use it as a DHCP instead of the first, it wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so. Connect the second Linksys router (Router2) to the main router (Router1).

You do not have to change any settings on Router1, but assign Router2 a static IP address that exists on your subnet, e.g 192.168.1.2. Turn off the DHCP server on the router, and have it use either a different SSID/key or the same SSID/key.

The key thing to do here is to turn off the DHCP server on Router2, and also to have it exists on your network as an AP (Access Point, not router!).

Give it a go, it should work.

P.S I'm not too sure how far you can go with a Cat-5 cable, but usually for SU folks, we use WDS to extend our wireless network coverage. Search for keywords "WDS, repeater"

Comment: So what settings make it an AP and not a router?  Just turning off DHCP does that?

Comment: You can say that. :) in extremely broad terms.

Comment: @Joel, make sure it's the DHCP *server* you're turning off, Automatic Configuration DHCP should still be on -> http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRT54GS/v5-v6/1.50.7/basic.htm.  Update your question with the brand and model of your routers so we can be more specific.

Comment: You can go 100m with a CAT5 cable to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend your network wirelessly I believe some routers have an "Access Point" mode which will simplify this.